# Are AdaptiveCards supported with MS Teams & the WebHook Connector?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Each time I try to send any example json from the documentation I get a HTTP 400 saying that "summary" or "text" is missing (which is indeed the case), however once I make a successful request, Teams displays an empty card

Is this thing supported at all??

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, still, today with Postman app, I was able to post an adaptive card json as a message attachment to Teams incoming webhook [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)] url. Microsoft Documentation is also available at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like still, webhooks are not supporting adaptiveCards. But there is a trick to send adaptive cards via incoming webhooks like below,
**Note: ${Replace it with Your AdapticveCARDShema Json Payload} would be your adaptive card Json payload**

```
{
   "type":"message",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
         "contentUrl":"null",
         "content":{ 
             ${Replace it with Your AdapticveCARDShema Json Payload}
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Webhooks do not yet support Adaptive Cards. We plan to add support for Adaptive Cards shortly.

Comment: Does "shortly" mean that we can expect this functionality in 2020? The documentation is very unclear as to what is and what is not supported by Teams' Webhooks feature.